# Is sunlight like a spotlight?

Tags: earth, sun, moon

It is believed that if earth would have no atmosphere then the sunlight would fall on earth like a spot light. According to this fact the sunlight on moon must fall like a spot light. Does it? Then why does it not appear so?

Comment: By "like a spot light"  do you mean the surface would be only partially illuminated?  If so, where have you got this idea from?

Comment: The sun emits light in full 360 degrees, much more like a light-bulb (lighting everything in it's line of sight) than a spot-light which has a parabolic mirror inside it to emit light in mostly a single direction.   If the moon was a near perfect mirror pointed to reflect light from the sun to the earth, then the moon would be similar to a spot-light but such things don't form naturally in nature.

If the earth had no atmosphere the sun would appear similar to it does, but it would be white, not yellow.  The blue sky would be gone, however and you could see stars during the day.

Comment: There is no atmosphere on the moon, but looking through a telescope it looks normally lit, no spotlight effects.

Comment: I'm sure there's a question elsewhere on the site discussing about this. I think it said something like *"it's already been done"*, showing a picture captured by Apollo.

Comment: Please be more precise about "spotlight effects". What, exactly, do you think the moon ought to look like?

Comment: Did you ever look at the moon trough a reasonable amateur telescope? I don't think you did.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you have not understood your "it is believed" source. Most likely, it is referring to the lack of diffuse light supplied by the atmosphere. Without this diffuse light, illuminated areas would be very bright, and shadows would be very dark. Like something illuminated by a spotlight.

And that's exactly what happens on the moon, with the modification that there is some indirect light produced by sunlight reflected from the surface. Failing to account for this reflected light produced one of the "The Apollo Landings Were A Hoax" conspiracy claims. And if that claim is still around, it can only be part of the "Mythbusters is a Tool of the Government" conspiracy. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wym04J_3Ls0

And please explain exactly why you believe "Then why does not it appear so?" What, exactly do you expect sunlight falling on the moon to look like, and why is that different from what you do see?

Comment: yep, that "Moon Hoax" claim is still alive and kicking, unfortunately.